# ExpressJS only sending 200 status code for index on first load. 304 everytime after that

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a local project running ExpressJS and I'm using ejs as my template engine. Whenever I start the server and go to the home page the index.html file renders properly, but every subsequent load of the index gives me the un-rendered index.html file and the status is 304. All other pages render fine everytime. If I restart the server, the first time I hit the home page it is rendered correctly, but still serves the un-rendered file after every page load after that. If I put a breakpoint in the route (I'm using WebStorm) I can hit the break point the first time, but never again. I assume this is because of the 304. I also have app.disable('etag'). Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This is what is the browser will display when receiving a 304 status.

```
<%- include('includes/header.html'); %>
<%- include('includes/navigation.html'); %>

<!-- Top Slider and Booking form -->
<div id="home-top-section">

    <!-- Main Slider -->
    <div id="main-slider">
        <div class="items">
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="assets/img/slider/1.jpg" alt="3"/><!-- Change the URL section based on your image\'s name -->
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="assets/img/slider/3.jpg" alt="3"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="assets/img/slider/4.jpg" alt="4"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="assets/img/slider/2.jpg" alt="2"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Booking Form -->
    <div class="booking-form-container container">
        <div class="booking-form-inner-container">
            <div id="main-booking-form" class="style-2">
                <h2>Find A <span>Room</span></h2>
                <form class="booking-form clearfix" action="#"><!-- Do Not remove the classes -->
                    <div class="input-daterange clearfix">
                        <div class="booking-fields col-xs-6 col-md-12">
                            <input placeholder="Choose check in date" class="datepicker-fields check-in" type="text" name="start" /><!-- Date Picker field ( Do Not remove the "datepicker-fields" class ) -->
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><!-- Date Picker Icon -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="booking-fields col-xs-6 col-md-12">
                            <input placeholder="Choose check out date" class="datepicker-fields check-out" type="text" name="end" />
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="booking-fields col-xs-6 col-md-12">
                        <!-- Select boxes ( you can change the items and its value based on your project's needs ) -->
                        <select name="room-type">
                            <option value="">How Many Adult?</option><!-- Select box items ( you can change the items and its value based on your project's needs ) -->
                            <option value="2">1</option>
                            <option value="3">2</option>
                            <option value="4">3</option>
                            <option value="5">4</option>
                            <option value="6">5</option>
                        </select>
                        <!-- End of Select boxes -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="booking-fields col-xs-6 col-md-12">
                        <select name="guest">
                            <option value="">How Many Children ?</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="booking-button-container">
                        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Check Availability" type="submit"/><!-- Submit button -->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Top Slider and Booking form -->

<!-- Luxury Rooms -->
<div id="luxury-rooms">
    <!-- Heading box -->
    <div class="heading-box">
        <h2>Luxury <span>Rooms</span></h2><!-- Title -->
        <div class="subtitle">Best rooms with Best services</div><!-- Subtitle -->
    </div>

    <!-- Room Box Container -->
    <div class="room-container container">
        <!-- Room box -->
        <div class="room-boxes">
            <img src="assets/img/rooms/1.jpg" alt="King Suit" class="room-img"><!-- Room Image -->
            <div class="room-details col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="title">King Suit</div><!-- Room title -->
                <div class="description"><!-- Room Description -->
                    Short description of rooms will be located in this section that you can describe some special features and equipment of rooms. Visitors can get more information about this rooms by clicking on "Details" button.
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Details</a><!-- Detail link -->
            </div>
            <div class="price-container col-xs-6 col-md-8">
                <div class="price">
                    <span>$550</span>
                    - Per Night
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Room box -->
        <div class="room-boxes right">
            <img src="assets/img/rooms/2.jpg" alt="Royal Suit" class="room-img">
            <div class="room-details col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="title">Royal Suit</div>
                <div class="description">
                    Short description of rooms will be located in this section that you can describe some special features and equipment of rooms. Visitors can get more information about this rooms by clicking on "Details" button.
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="price-container col-xs-6 col-md-8">
                <div class="price">
                    <span>$490</span>
                    - Per Night
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Room box -->
        <div class="room-boxes">
            <img src="assets/img/rooms/3.jpg" alt="Deluxe Two-bedroom Suite" class="room-img">
            <div class="room-details col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="title">Deluxe Two-bedroom Suite</div>
                <div class="description">
                    Short description of rooms will be located in this section that you can describe some special features and equipment of rooms. Visitors can get more information about this rooms by clicking on "Details" button.
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Details</a>
            </div>
            <div class="price-container col-xs-6 col-md-8">
                <div class="price">
                    <span>$370</span>
                    - Per Night
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Luxury Rooms -->

<!-- Special Packages -->
<div id="special-packages" class="container">
    <!-- Heading box -->
    <div class="heading-box">
        <h2>Special <span>Packages</span></h2><!-- Title -->
        <div class="subtitle">Choose one of our special offers</div><!-- Subtitle -->
    </div>

    <!-- Package Container -->
    <div class="package-container clearfix">
        <!-- Package Box -->
        <div class="package-box wow fadeInUp col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="package-inner">
                <div class="title">Diamond</div>
                <div class="price"><span>$450</span>per night</div>
                <div class="package-details">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Flight Ticket</li>
                        <li>Restaurant ( Lunch / Dinner )</li>
                        <li>Music Concert</li>
                        <li>Airport Pick-up</li>
                        <li>Sport Activities</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Select Package</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Package Box -->
        <div class="package-box wow fadeInUp col-sm-6 col-md-4" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
            <div class="package-inner">
                <div class="title">Gold</div>
                <div class="price"><span>$340</span>per night</div>
                <div class="package-details">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Flight Ticket</li>
                        <li>Restaurant ( Lunch )</li>
                        <li>Music Concert ( 50% off )</li>
                        <li>Airport Pick-up</li>
                        <li>Sport Activities</li>                       
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Select Package</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Package Box -->
        <div class="package-box wow fadeInUp col-sm-6 col-md-4" data-wow-delay="1s">
            <div class="package-inner">
                <div class="title">Silver</div>
                <div class="price"><span>$230</span>per night</div>
                <div class="package-details">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Flight Ticket</li>
                        <li>Restaurant ( 20% off Lunch )</li>
                        <li>Music Concert ( 30% off )</li>
                        <li>Airport Pick-up</li>
                        <li>Sport Activities</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Select Package</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Special Packages -->

<!-- Gallery -->
<div id="gallery">
    <!-- Heading box -->
    <div class="heading-box">
        <h2>Pinar <span>Gallery</span></h2><!-- Title -->
    </div>

    <!-- Gallery Container -->
    <div class="gallery-container">
        <div class="sort-section">
            <div class="sort-section-container">
                <div class="sort-handle">Filters</div>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".restaurant">Restaurant</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".bars">Bars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".pool">Pool</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".rooms">Rooms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".lobby">Lobby</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="image-main-box clearfix">
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3 lobby">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/1.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/1.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Great View">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Great</span> View</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-6 pool">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/2.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/2.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Outdoor Pool">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Outdoor</span> Pool</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3 bars">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/3.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/3.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Delicious Foods">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Delicious</span> Foods</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3 restaurant">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/4.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/4.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="International Foods">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>International</span> Foods</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3 pool">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/5.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/5.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Cozy Spaces">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Cozy</span> Spaces</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3 rooms">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/6.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/6.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Comfortable Rooms">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Comfortable </span> Rooms</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3 pool">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/7.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/7.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Relaxation Spaces">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Relaxation</span> Spaces</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-xs-6 col-md-6 pool">
                <figure>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/8.jpg" alt="11"/>
                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/8.jpg" class="more-details" data-title="Indoor Pool">Enlarge</a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span>Indoor</span> Pool</h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">More ...</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Gallery -->

<%- include('includes/footer.html'); %>
```

instead of the rendered version. Notice the includes at the top and bottom of the page.

Comment: 304 means "not modified", there is absolutely nothing wrong with that status, especially not when it's a static file.

Comment: @tomalak the problem isn’t the 304. The problem is the fact that I’m getting and in-rendered version of the file. If I received a rendered version all would be good. Also, for my apps purposes I need to always get 200 and basically be able to hit that route. So while there is nothing technically wrong with 304 status I need to bypass it. I have app.disable(‘etag’) but that doesn’t seem to be doing anything.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 304 has no body, not rendered and not otherwise. It tells the browser to use whatever is in its cache. If the browser received a proper version of the document the first time (status 200) then it wlll use the same version the second time.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry for the late response. i was out of town. what i don't get is that i ONLY get a 304 for the index page. all other pages never send 304. and i have explicitly disabled app.disable('etag'). I'm using ejs as my templating engine. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: ETag does not have anything to do with it, but `Last-Modified`. The browser will send `If-Modified-Since` with a subsequent request an the server will respond with `304 Not Modified` if nothing has been modified. I still don't understand what your actual issue is. 304 is a *good* result. It means you are saving bandwidth and the client loads faster because it does not have to wait a second time for data it already has. This is not the problem you must solve. The problem you must solve is why it is even possible for the client to request an un-rendered view in the first place.

Comment: @Tomalak i have 3 issues. 1), when 304 is sent, for some reason the browser is displaying the un-rendered version of the index.html file. I've updated the above to show what i mean. 2) why is every other page NOT giving a 304 message when they also have not been modified. 3) for the purposes of my application, i need to NOT have a 304 returned. i understand that it's a good result, but for my application it's actually not a good thing.

Comment: Is the server rendering the template, or the client?

Comment: @Tomalak server is. client side is just static HTML rendered from the express server.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. So my answer to your questions before would be: 1) The browser is not supposed to even be able to request the raw view template. Not by accident and certainly not casually. So that means there's a server mis-configuration here. 2) I don't know. `Not-Modified` only works out of the box for static files like `.html` or `.jpg` and must be specifically implemented for dynamic responses. 3) I am sure that's what you think because it appears to you as if 304 is causing you trouble. It's not. The mis-configuration from #1 is.

Comment: @Tomalak ok, but for my apps purposes i need the route to run everytime i refresh the page. Since i'm getting the 304, the route doesn't always run. In the route function i have to make a call to the DB to check a setting and that will determine if the template changes or not, but i need it to run every time you refresh the page. Is there a way to tell express to run the route callback even if it's a 304 situation?

Comment: You are not listening to me. The browser should not be able to load the raw template file. You have set up your server wrong. No route should exist that allows such a thing. Combating the 304 is not what you should be doing.

Comment: @Tomalak after looking further into this (and you are probably going to hate me more than you already do after reading this) but it was a simple issue of having my templates as .html. I was using a template that I bought and was using ejs as my templating engine so I could use includes in the templates. The issue is, since these are .html files and I use express.static, it was causing some weird conflict and sending the static unrendered .html file. All I did was change the .html to .ejs for all files and it's working perfectly as expected. Apologies for the run around. I'm still learning.

Comment: I don't hate you, no worries. :) In fact, I was thinking exactly along those lines. I was even about to suggest simply renaming the templates from *.html to *.ejs but I am not familiar enough with how ejs works on node/express to know if that's correct, and I did not want to rummage through the documentation just for that. That's why I kept it in the comments instead of writing an answer and kept pressing the point that static file handling and server mis-configuration is the real reason, hoping that you would catch on and look in the right spot. Eventually, you did, so… mission accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue was simply because I was using .html templates instead of .ejs. Word to the wise, if you buy a template that has static .html files and want to use a templating engine such as .ejs, make sure you change .html to .ejs or you will run into all types of issues.